# Is there Application_End from Global.asax in Owin?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, owin, katana

[`Startup.cs`](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-startup-class-detection) is a new way to initialize your app instead of `Application_Start` in Global.asax and it's fine. But is there a place to put my teardown logic, for example this:

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
  protected void Application_End()
  {
    // Release you ServiceBroker listener
    SqlDependency.Stop(connString);
  }
}
```

Looked in [Microsoft.Owin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) namespace but it only seems to have `OwinStartupAttribute`. Does this mean that application  lifecycle events are still processed by `System.Web.HttpApplication` instance and are not supported by OWIN specification?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`AppProperties`, found in `Microsoft.Owin.BuilderProperties`, exposes the `CancellationToken` for `OnAppDisposing`.

You can get this *token* and register a *callback* to it

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var properties = new AppProperties(app.Properties);
        CancellationToken token = properties.OnAppDisposing;
        if (token != CancellationToken.None)
        {
            token.Register(() =>
            {
                // do stuff
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16):

I packaged this up in a little helper so you can do this:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.OnDisposing(() =>
        {
            // do stuff
        });
    }
}
```

The helper:

```
static class AppBuilderExtensions
{
    public static void OnDisposing(this IAppBuilder app, Action cleanup)
    {
        var properties = new AppProperties(app.Properties);
        var token = properties.OnAppDisposing;
        if (token != CancellationToken.None)
        {
            token.Register(cleanup);
        }
    }
}
```