# execute code on asp.net 5 application shutdown

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I have a couple processes running in the background that I'd like to gracefully stop when application is terminating due to an app pool recycle. Does anyone know how to handle this gracefully?

I am looking for something similar to Application_End in the older versions of ASP.NET.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there Application\_End from Global.asax in Owin?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27444924/is-there-application-end-from-global-asax-in-owin)

Comment: As of today, there's a more up-to-date Q&A here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35257287/kestrel-shutdown-function-in-startup-cs-in-asp-net-core