# Kestrel shutdown function in Startup.cs in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Is there a shutdown function when using `Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel`? `ASP.NET Core` (formerly `ASP.NET vNext`) clearly has a Startup sequence, but no mention of shutdown sequence and how to handle clean closure.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

In ASP.NET Core you can register to the cancellation tokens provided by `IApplicationLifetime`

```cs
public class Startup 
{
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IApplicationLifetime applicationLifetime) 
    {
        applicationLifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register(OnShutdown);
    }

    private void OnShutdown()
    {
         // Do your cleanup here
    }
}
```

`IApplicationLifetime` is also exposing cancellation tokens for `ApplicationStopped` and `ApplicationStarted` as well as a `StopApplication()` method to stop the application.

#### For .NET Core 3.0+

From comments [@Horkrine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6747751/horkrine)

> For .NET Core 3.0+ it is recommended to use IHostApplicationLifetime instead, as IApplicationLifetime will be deprecated soon. The rest will still work as written above with the new service

Comment: Is this supposed to work on all OSes and servers? I haven't been able to get it working on OSX + Kestrel.

Comment: It should work on all platforms, if not it may be a bug. There are some old issues on github, maybe you try davidfowl's workaround in https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/151 otherwise try opening an issue at https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues may be a bug, it's still in RC1 preparing for RC2

Comment: @opiethehokie: Also may be related to https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/516. It's for linux, but SIGINT and SIGTERM are used on MacOS too as far as I know. Not familiar enough to know which of the signals MacOS does send to stop the process. Also may be interesting to know if you are using dnx core 1.0 or against the full mono framework

Comment: this is with dnx core. None of SIGINT, SIGTERM, or CTRL+C (which as far as I know is SIGINT) result in any output from my OnShutdown(). In issue 516 it sounds like at least CTRL+C should be working, so I may open another issue after a little more investigation to make sure I'm not just doing something dumb.

Comment: this works for me when running from the console but when running from IIS the process is simply stopped - the event is not called

Comment: For Windows10, IIS 10 (Dev) I am getting the Start stuff working, but there is no graceful stoppage signalled.  This is the case for either terminating debug with Shift-F5 or stopping the process in IIS10 via the sys tray app.

Comment: Is there a way to pass a parameter into `OnShutDown`? I need to use a `DbContext` to save some data before shutdown

Comment: @MichaelTranchida: Sorry its late, but if you can pass a delegate as shutdown method and use `IApplicationBuilder` within it, it will capture its context and you can resolve a scope and from it a DbContext

Comment: For .NET Core 3.0+ it is recommended to use `IHostApplicationLifetime` instead, as `IApplicationLifetime ` will be deprecated soon. The rest will still work as written above with the new service

Comment: What are u supposed to do in OnShutdown? I dont see how that helps. Lets say u have an unknown currently ongoing requests in Controllers, it can be 1, 10 or 1000, you dont know. You want them all to finish. How does OnShutdown help? I was hoping for some way, saying "When all HttpContext are gone, meaning, when there are no more requests being handled, shut down please".

Answer (score 34):

In addition to the original answer, I had an error while trying to wire the IApplicationLifetime within the constructor.

I solved this by doing:

```
public class Startup 
{
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app) 
    {
        var applicationLifetime = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IApplicationLifetime>();
        applicationLifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register(OnShutdown);
    }

    private void OnShutdown()
    {
         // Do your cleanup here
    }
}
```

Comment: This works without using a Startup class when you manually configure your webhost from main.

Answer (score 4):

This class is now obsolete, please refer to the new interface **IHostApplicationLifetime**. More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihostapplicationlifetime?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.0).

Answer (score 4):

I solved it with the application lifetime callback events

**Startup.cs**

```
public void Configure(IHostApplicationLifetime appLifetime) {
 appLifetime.ApplicationStarted.Register(() => {
  Console.WriteLine("Press Ctrl+C to shut down.");
 });

 appLifetime.ApplicationStopped.Register(() => {
  Console.WriteLine("Terminating application...");
  System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
 });
}
```

---

**Program.cs**

Also, use `UseConsoleLifetime()` while building the host.

```
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).UseConsoleLifetime(opts => opts.SuppressStatusMessages = true);
```

Comment: What are u supposed to do in `appLifetime.ApplicationStopped.Register`? I dont see how that helps. Lets say u have an unknown currently ongoing requests in Controllers, it can be 1, 10 or 1000, you dont know. You want them all to finish. How does that metod help? I was hoping for some way, saying "When all HttpContext are gone, meaning, when there are no more requests being handled, shut down please"?

Comment: I didn't have a requirement to wait for all requests. my website was a local website that starts up in console application. so when the user presses  CTRL+C I want to shut it down immediately.

Answer (score 3):

When using .NET 6 without a Startup class, you can access the `ApplicationStopping` `CancellationToken` via the built web application in Program.cs, e.g.

```cs
var app = builder.Build();
...
app.Lifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register(() => ...);
...
app.Run();
```

Answer (score 3):

In .Net 6 if you are not using Startup.cs. You could use ApplicationStopping method in Program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(new WebApplicationOptions
{   
    Args = args,
    ContentRootPath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),
    WebRootPath = "wwwroot"
});

var app = builder.Build();

app.Lifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register(() =>
{
 // Do Something
});

app.Run();
```