# .NET Core app in IIS/ Azure App Service: handle server shutdown programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am currently having an ASP.NET Core application that is attached to an IIS/ Azure App Service using the following web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
        </handlers>
        <aspNetCore processPath=".\MyDotNetCoreApp.exe" arguments="" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\stdout.txt" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The application has been built with "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel" and "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration" added as dependencies and uses the following bootstrapping code:

```
IWebHost Host = new WebHostBuilder()
  .UseKestrel()
  .UseIISIntegration()
  .UseStartup<WebSocketServerConduit>()
  .Build();
```

Everything works magnificently; however, once the App Service is shutdown, the app is simply terminated.
Is there any way to catch the "shutdown signal" of the IIS/ App Service and thus perform cleanup tasks?

Help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance and best regards
-Simon

Comment: Take a look at the IApplicationLifetime interface.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35257287/