# Where can I log an ASP.NET Core app's start/stop/error events?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

In old ASP.NET, in the `Global.asax.cs` class, I would log when the app starts, stops and throws unhandled exceptions:

- `Application_Start()`
- `Application_End()`
- `Application_Error()`

How do I do the same in ASP.NET Core? It has a `Startup` class, but it is for configuration.

Where do I hook into the app's start/stop/error events?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Note: For .NET Core 3.0 or later, this answer is obsolete. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41675577/where-can-i-log-an-asp-net-core-apps-start-stop-error-events/64866510#64866510) instead.

You need to use [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IApplicationLifetime](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions/IApplicationLifetime.cs)

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Triggered when the application host has fully started and is about to wait
    /// for a graceful shutdown.
    /// </summary>
    CancellationToken ApplicationStarted { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Triggered when the application host is performing a graceful shutdown.
    /// Requests may still be in flight. Shutdown will block until this event completes.
    /// </summary>
    CancellationToken ApplicationStopping { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Triggered when the application host is performing a graceful shutdown.
    /// All requests should be complete at this point. Shutdown will block
    /// until this event completes.
    /// </summary>
    CancellationToken ApplicationStopped { get; }
```

Instance of IApplicationLifetime could be obtained in `Configure` method. Also add ILoggerFactory here:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IApplicationLifetime applicationLifetime, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    // use applicationLifetime
}
```

Having `ILoggerFactory`, you can [create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging) instance of `ILogger`:

```
var logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger("StartupLogger");
```

So you just need to create a property in the Startup class to persist the instance of `ILogger` (or `ILoggerFactory`, if you would like to create different ligger instance for different events). To summarize:

```
public class Startup 
{
    private ILogger _logger;

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IApplicationLifetime applicationLifetime, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory) 
    {
        applicationLifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register(OnShutdown);
        ... 
        // add logger providers
        // loggerFactory.AddConsole()
        ...
        _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger("StartupLogger");
    }

    private void OnShutdown()
    {
         // use _logger here;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there something similar for unhandled exceptions?

Comment: These methods [can be used](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35257670/7059613) to detect start/stopping/stopped. But how would you do logging in there? An instance of the logger cannot be retrieved because you are in the `Startup` class?

Comment: You use middleware for things like logging now - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging

Comment: I want to log to SQL Server using EF Core, so I don't want to persist an instance on the `Startup` class, can I pass a parameter to `OnShutDown`, `OnStartUp`? I tried just creating a `DbContext` within the shutdown method (using InMemory), but for some reason it doesn't work. Using Asp.Net Core 2.0 btw

Comment: You should now use IHostApplicationLifetime (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-3.1#ihostapplicationlifetime) and register your implementation at startup, eg `services.AddHostedService<LifetimeEventsHostedService>();`

Answer (score 13):

I didn't like [@neustart47](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2876310/neustart47) answer as it was unnecessarily complex but he is right that `IApplicationLifetime` is obsolete.

Taken from the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-3.1#ihostapplicationlifetime)

```
//  1. Add the interface `IHostedService` to the class you would like
//     to be called during an application event. 
internal class LifetimeEventsHostedService : IHostedService
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private readonly IHostApplicationLifetime _appLifetime;

    // 2. Inject `IHostApplicationLifetime` through dependency injection in the constructor.
    public LifetimeEventsHostedService(
        ILogger<LifetimeEventsHostedService> logger, 
        IHostApplicationLifetime appLifetime)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _appLifetime = appLifetime;
    }

    // 3. Implemented by `IHostedService`, setup here your event registration. 
    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _appLifetime.ApplicationStarted.Register(OnStarted);
        _appLifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register(OnStopping);
        _appLifetime.ApplicationStopped.Register(OnStopped);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    // 4. Implemented by `IHostedService`, setup here your shutdown registration.
    //    If you have nothing to stop, then just return `Task.CompletedTask`
    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private void OnStarted()
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("OnStarted has been called.");

        // Perform post-startup activities here
    }

    private void OnStopping()
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("OnStopping has been called.");

        // Perform on-stopping activities here
    }

    private void OnStopped()
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("OnStopped has been called.");

        // Perform post-stopped activities here
    }
}
```

**Additional Info**

After adding the class above to your project, go to your `Program.cs` file and add a call like the following to inject the service (and instantiate the class):
`builder.Services.AddHostedService<LifetimeEventsHostedService>();`

Once you add that, build and run the app again, you'll see the log statements...

```
"OnStarted has been called."
```

etc.

Done!

Comment: This is working as expected. `LifetimeEventsHostedService` must be [registered in the startup as a hosted service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio).

Comment: No explanation of how to call this from Configure

Comment: @PaulMcCarthy, this should not be called from configure. It gets automatically called

Comment: @JasonLandbridge that's incorrect. `LifetimeEventsHostedService` needs to be add as a service in `Program.cs` file with `services.AddHostedService<LifetimeEventsHostedService>();`

Answer (score 6):

Please see [CaptureStartupErrors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/hosting?tabs=aspnetcore2x#capture-startup-errors) and the method `.CaptureStartupErrors(true)` that will help you find issues.

This is especially handy when something runs perfect on localhost but fails in Azure.

Here is my usual config for NetCore Web Apps:

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) => WebHost
            .CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .CaptureStartupErrors(true)
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseAzureAppServices()
            .Build();
```

In Azure App Service you can then find the logs in the log stream in Kudu Tools `https://<appname>.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/logstream`

Comment: The linked page no longer mentions `CaptureStartupErrors` - is this still needed?

Answer (score 3):

Using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IApplicationLifetime` suggested in the top answer now is obsolete.

```
[Obsolete("This type is obsolete and will be removed in a future version. The recommended alternative is Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostApplicationLifetime.", false)]
public interface IApplicationLifetime
```

Use `IHostApplicationLifetime` to fire callback when the application shuts down.

Add somewhere:

```
public static async Task WaitForShutdownAsync(this IHost host)
{
    // Get the lifetime object from the DI container
    var applicationLifetime = host.Services.GetService<IHostApplicationLifetime>();

    // Create a new TaskCompletionSource called waitForStop
    var waitForStop = new TaskCompletionSource<object>(TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously);

    // Register a callback with the ApplicationStopping cancellation token
    applicationLifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register(obj =>
    {
        var tcs = (TaskCompletionSource<object>)obj;

        //PUT YOUR CODE HERE 

        // When the application stopping event is fired, set 
        // the result for the waitForStop task, completing it
        tcs.TrySetResult(null);
    }, waitForStop);

    // Await the Task. This will block until ApplicationStopping is triggered,
    // and TrySetResult(null) is called
    await waitForStop.Task;

    // We're shutting down, so call StopAsync on IHost
    await host.StopAsync();
}
```

Then I use it in Program.cs:

```
var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
host.WaitForShutdownAsync();
```

The same for other callbacks.
More info you can find [here](https://andrewlock.net/introducing-ihostlifetime-and-untangling-the-generic-host-startup-interactions/)

If I missed something please let me know

Comment: Does `host.WaitForShutdownAsync()` take the place of `host.Run()`.  I'm so confused. Maybe I missed that part in the article.