# How can I know when Kestrel has started listening?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, kestrel

I need to notify `systemd` that my service has started up successfully, and a task it needs to run after startup requires that the server is *already listening* on the target Unix domain socket.

I am using `IWebHost::Run` to start the server, and that is a blocking call. Additionally, I am unable to find any obvious way to set a delegate or callback event for successful initialization.

Anyone?

Answer (score 4):

You may use [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IApplicationLifetime](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions/IApplicationLifetime.cs):

```
/// <summary>
/// Triggered when the application host has fully started and is about to wait
/// for a graceful shutdown.
/// </summary>
CancellationToken ApplicationStarted { get; }
```

Look into this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41676005/2833802) for the configuration example.

Answer (score 3):

- On `.Net Core 1.x` it is safe to just run `IWebHost.Start()` and assume that the server is initialized afterwards (instead of `Run()` that blocks the thread). Check the [source](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/rel/1.1.2/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting/Internal/WebHost.cs#L100).

  ```
  var host = new WebHostBuilder()
      .UseKestrel()
      (...)
      .Build();

  host.Start();
  ```
- If you are using `.NET Core 2.0 Preview 1` (or later), the [source is different](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/rel/1.1.2/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting/Internal/WebHost.cs), the synchronous method is not available anymore so you should await `IWebHost.StartAsync()` and assume everything is ready afterwards.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing; the comment about Start() being async is just erroneous.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I ended up going with, for now. Seems to be working fine:

```
host.Start();

Log.Information("Press Ctrl+C to shut down...");
Console.CancelKeyPress += OnConsoleCancelKeyPress;

var waitHandles = new WaitHandle[] {
    CancelTokenSource.Token.WaitHandle
};

WaitHandle.WaitAll(waitHandles);
Log.Information("Shutting down...");
```

Then, in the Ctrl+C event handler:

```
private static void OnConsoleCancelKeyPress(object sender, ConsoleCancelEventArgs e)
{
    Log.Debug("Got Ctrl+C from console.");
    CancelTokenSource.Cancel();
}
```

Comment: How does this code helps you detect when Kestrel has finished initializing?

Comment: Didn't you say it was safe to assume Kestrel was ready after the Start() call unless I'm using 2.0 preview 1? That comment about it being async shouldn't be there.

Comment: I asked because I didn't know and your answer was not clear to me. I thought you were hacking the Cancel event to detect end of the initialization. Then researched a little bit and found that Start is safe, so I posted it, and assumed your code worked by miracle, if at all. Now I believe you coded how to block the current thread properly. All the misunderstanding could have been avoided with some wordings in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

A working sample from .NET Core 6:

In your Program.cs, you will have the following (with more or less embellishment, depending on the middleware):

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

/* ... kestrel configuration, middleware setup ... */

var app = builder.Build();

app.Services.GetService<IHostApplicationLifetime>()!.ApplicationStarted.Register(() =>
{
    /* any code you put here will execute
     * after the host has started listening */
    Console.WriteLine("Kestrel has started listening");
});

/* this is a blocking call.
 * the start event occurs from "in there" */
app.Run();
```

Working principle: The event handler with the `Console.WriteLine` call will be called after `app.Run()` is already blocking the main thread, at the exact moment when the server is first ready and will accept requests.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: it explains how "you know that kestrel has started listening"

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to overcome the issue.

1- I registered `ApplicationStopped` event. So that it brute force terminates the app by calling `Kill()` method of the current process.

```
public void Configure(IHostApplicationLifetime appLifetime) {
 appLifetime.ApplicationStarted.Register(() => {
  Console.WriteLine("Press Ctrl+C to shut down.");
 });

 appLifetime.ApplicationStopped.Register(() => {
  Console.WriteLine("Terminating application...");
  System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
 });
}
```

[See IHostApplicationLifetime docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihostapplicationlifetime?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.0)

---

2- Don't forget to use the `UseConsoleLifetime()` while building the host.

```
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).UseConsoleLifetime(opts => opts.SuppressStatusMessages = true);
```

[See useconsolelifetime docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.hostinghostbuilderextensions.useconsolelifetime?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.0)