# asp.net api needs to globally return a status during shutdown

Tags: asp.net-core

We have a system, which is not public facing, that has to do a bunch of work when it goes down for an update, etc.

During this time, the REST interface can still receive requests and I'm looking for a global solution where any call would not be processed by the regular controllers but just return a unique code (for example a 503).
I'd like to avoid something like "if (shutdown) ..." in each controller method :)

Is there a provision for something like this in the asp.net core api?

Answer (score 1):

You may try to register [IApplicationLifetime.ApplicationStopping](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions/IApplicationLifetime.cs) action to catch up when shutdown is starting. But note that this is only for a graceful shutdown.

```
/// <summary>
/// Triggered when the application host is performing a graceful shutdown.
/// Requests may still be in flight. Shutdown will block until this event completes.
/// </summary>
CancellationToken ApplicationStopping { get; }
```

Look into SO [Where can I log an ASP.NET Core app's start/stop/error events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41675577/where-can-i-log-an-asp-net-core-apps-start-stop-error-events/41676005#41676005) for implementation sample.

---

Then you may add a simple middleware that stops the pipeline execution and returns 503 status while an app is stopping:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            bool yourFlag = ... ;// should be true if application topping;

            if (yourFlag)
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = 503;
                // stop further pipeline execution
                return;
            }
            await next.Invoke();
        });
     ...
}
```

Comment: We know when the app is shutting down, what I'm looking for is to get every single rest call to the app to return a 503 status during that time.

Comment: @Thomas ok so you may add a simple middleware that will return a 503 status for all request at that time. And make sure that it is located at the beginning of the pipeline. I have updated post