# What happens after host.Run()?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Like the title says I'm interested to know how Program gets terminated.  The line after host.Run() appears to never execute.

My specific goal is to dispose of the KeepAliveTimer upon shutting down the site so all answers that accomplish that objective are welcome.

I suppose I could wrap all of Main() in a using block but given the issue I'm having here I'm still not convinced it would work.  I've had problems with memory leaks with timers in the past thus my phobia.

```
public class Program
{
    private static Timer KeepAliveTimer;
    private static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        KeepAliveTimer = new Timer(x => CallAPI(), null, 0, 5000);

        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();

        host.Run();
        KeepAliveTimer.Dispose();  // Not happening
    }


    private static void CallAPI()
    {

        // etc...        
    }
}
```

*Edit*

per comment and link posted by Tseng

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        //...

       // also does not work when IApplicationLifetime is injected 


        var appLifetime = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IApplicationLifetime>();
        appLifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register(() => {
            KeepAliveTimer.Dispose(); // not called
        });

        appLifetime.ApplicationStopped.Register(() => {
            KeepAliveTimer.Dispose(); // not called
        });
    }
```

Comment: How did you shut it down? Ctrl+C? Let IIS shut it down? crash? Check out my previous here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35257287/kestrel-shutdown-function-in-startup-cs-in-asp-net-core/35257670#35257670 on how register/react to shutdown events using cancellation tokens ASP.NET Core offers

Comment: @Tseng Please see updated question.  Attempt shutdown via all the above, running under iis express and kestrel.  Prod app is running iis