# Recycling Kestrel on Linux

Tags: c#, linux, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

What is the recommended approach for recycling self-hosted `AspNet.Core` applications running `Kestrel` webserver on Linux? Or is it not necessary to recycle at all? (If they are running under IIS, it would recycle them periodically and gracefully)

Comment: There is nothing out of the box as far as I am concerned. But you can do anything between running certain cron.d scripts (which either restart regularly or on certain conditions), use docker orchestration do achieve the same. In boils down to a `kill -9 <pid>`. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35257670/455493) on how to register to the shutdown event to handle graceful shutdowns. Everything else is out of scope and to broad

Answer (score 1):

if you are running kestrel as a systemd service you could use crontab:

```
0 * * * * sudo systemctl restart kestrel-servicename
```

or if systemd version is >= 229, you can use the RuntimeMaxSec option, which terminates the service after it has been running for the given period of time.

```
[Service]
Restart=always
RuntimeMaxSec=3600
```