# Shutting down gracefully: What is the difference between AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit vs. appLifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register?

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a asp.net-core 2.1 webapi project running in a kubernetes cluster and i want to implement a graceful shutdown.

My research let me to two different approaches:
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit
and
appLifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register

My Question is : which method is the preferred one?

Comment: `ApplicationStopping` is an cancellation token. You can register to it and will be triggered when the application is about to shut down. Its part of kestrel/asp.net core. The first one is rather generic and not specific to asp.net core. See my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35257287/kestrel-shutdown-function-in-startup-cs-in-asp-net-core/35257670#35257670). With the appl lifetime you have a more finegrained control

Comment: The stopping triggers when the application is about to stop and you get a few seconds to clear up the work and gracefully shut it down. `ApplicationStopped` triggers just before once the time is over and the app is killed after that (just giving you enough time to log it etc.)